# ng-repeat to index into array

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs app that streams data via ajax, and I would like to ng-repeat over the data.  I have the data streaming and displaying but now I want to templatize the objects.  The issue I am running into is that I am using ng-repeat simply to index into an array in the controller.  I now need to have a

```
    <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <div class="span3" data-ng-repeat="col in cols">
            //displays the raw json fine
            {{ data[$parent.$index * numColumns + $index] }}                           
            // also displays the raw json
            {{ item = data[$parent.$index * numColumns + $index] }}                           
            <div>Id: {{item.Id}} </div>
            <div>Title: {{ item.ClientJobTitle }}</div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

I could always repeat the array index expression for each property, but there will be a couple dozen properties, so the code will be ugly and all the repeated calculations will slow things down.

What is the right (angular) way to do this?

**Update**
I need it to be responsive too, I will be adjusting the number of columns on the fly based on window width.

**Update**
I guess what I really want is something like the following non-working example

```
     <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <div class="span3" data-ng-repeat="col in cols">
            <div ng-model="data[$parent.$index * numColumns + $index]">
                <!-- Here $model would refer to the ng-model above -->
                <div>Id: {{$model.Id}} </div>
                <div>Title: {{ $model.Title }}</div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what the initial data looks like? Having trouble visualizing how `item` is related to `rows`. Maybe put together a plunk?

Comment: @jszobody http://plnkr.co/edit/Bd5tYa7IxMb0ALtUigrz?p=preview

Comment: You could create a directive with a transclud that would take the list, row, and column and have the item in scope for the transclud section. I know knockout has the with statement which is sort of similar, but I don't think angular does

Answer (score 1):

You've probably handled the issue some way, but it's worth a mention that your non-working example is absolutely possible, even without directives:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[])
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.numColumns = 2
 $scope.rows = [1,2,3]
 $scope.cols = [1,2]
 $scope.data = [
  {Id:'abc',Title:'cde'},
  {Id:'qwe',Title:'rty'},
  {Id:'asd',Title:'fgh'},
  {Id:'foo',Title:'bar'},
  {Id:'uni',Title:'corn'},
  {Id:'mag',Title:'ic'},
 ];
 $scope.change1 = function(){
   $scope.numColumns = 2
  $scope.rows = [1,2,3]
  $scope.cols = [1,2]
 }
  $scope.change2 = function(){
   $scope.numColumns = 3
  $scope.rows = [1,2]
  $scope.cols = [1,2,3]
 }
});
```

```css
.span3 {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:5px;
 margin:5px;
 background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="change1()">2x3</button>
    <button ng-click="change2()">3x2</button>

 <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <div class="span3" data-ng-repeat="col in cols">
            <div>
       {{($model = data[$parent.$index * numColumns + $index])?'':''}}

                <!-- Here $model would refer to the ng-model above -->
                <div>Id: {{$model.Id}} </div>
                <div>Title: {{ $model.Title }}</div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

basically, it's possible to create such variable as "$model" on the fly, inside expression:

```
{{($model = data[$parent.$index * numColumns + $index])?'':''}}
```

It won't be printed itself, it'll be responsive, working inside ng-repeat and all. Still, it's kind of workaround, and directive might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this would be to simply loop through the items themselves, and ditch all the numRows and numColumns.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Qu6X5FnZY3TpgyNjnBXy?p=preview

That is outputting exactly what yours is doing, with *much* simpler angularjs code.

It seems that you are using the row/column counts to limit how many items you display on a row horizontally. I think you can handle this with pure css, you can see in my plunk I'm limiting the width on a parent container. I'm doing it manually, but you could easily attach a dynamic css class to the parent container and have more flexible control over how many items appear on a row.

Comment: That works if I want the section fixed width, but in this case I need it to be responsive (I plan to adjust the column count based on window dimensions, just haven't gotten to that part yet).

Comment: CSS can adjust to window dimensions even easier. Create a handful of different CSS class names if you have to, apply them with ng-class="getRowClassNams()" and move all the width logic to that. It still keeps your loop clean.

Comment: yeah, css makes it easy...its already handled by bootstrap in my case (the row and span3 classes in the code).  I plan to adjust the span3 class as you suggest, but I need the row class for the responsive behaviour if I understand bootstrap correctly.